# Install yarn version 3.3 in Nodejs docker image version 18.3

Tags: node.js, docker, gitlab, yarnpkg, cicd

I want to create a CICD pipeline for a node js application.

I am using gitlab runner with image of nodejs 18.2 version.

In code, dependency are Nodejs version should be 18.x with yarn 3.x but the avaiable docker image for 18.x versio is having 1.x yarn version only.

What is the best way to solve this problem?